# Link color in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, colors, hyperlink

I'm changing the color of the link in a web page. The CSS:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
  color: #009900 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #009900;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.lemmas a:link, a:visited, a:active {
  color: #014e68 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.lemmas a:hover {
  background-color: #014e68;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.feel a:link, a:visited, a:active {
  color: #ff3300;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.feel a:hover {
  background-color: #ff3300;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

The links are colored only with the last color, the one assigned to the class `feel` in Firefox. In Internet Explorer the colors are shown perfectly. Where is the problem?

Comment: You could be more general. a:hover, a:visited, ..... {text-decoration:none;}. Then you don't have to repeat you self. You should clean this up. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think these selectors:

```
.lemmas a:link, a:visited, a:active {}
.feel a:link, a:visited, a:active {}
```

Should look like:

```
.lemmas a:link, .lemmas a:visited, .lemmas a:active {}
.feel a:link, .feel a:visited, .feel a:active {}
```

If not, `:visited` and `:active` pseudoclasses would be applied to all visited and active links.